# Taking the derivative of $x^{\sin(e^x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How am I suppose to take the derivative of $f(x)=x^{\sin(e^x)}$?

What should I make $u$ equals?

I tried to make $u=\sin(e^x)$ and $u=e^x$ but they didn't work.

Comment: Why are you using $u$-substitution? You're taking the derivative of it not the integral.

Comment: Hint:  How to you take the derivative of $f(g(x))$?  If you don't know look for "chain rule".

Comment: @karakfa The chain rule does not apply here because this is actually $f(x, g(h(x)))$. It is not a chain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Here, you want to (start off) by using *logarithmic differentiation* - that is, take the derivative of $\ln f(x)$, then use it to find the derivative of $f$.

Note that
$$
\ln(x^{\sin(e^x)})=\sin(e^x)\ln(x).
$$
Try differentiating that.  Then, use 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln f(x)\right]=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$
to solve for $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
write $f(x)=e^{\ln x \sin e^x} = e^{u(x)v(x)}$; then, apply the usual rules to get
$$
f^\prime(x) = (uv)^\prime(x) e^{u(x)v(x)} = (u^\prime(x)v(x) + u(x)v^\prime(x)) f(x)
$$
using the fact that $v^\prime(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sin e^x = e^x \cos e^x$ (composition and differentiation).